# jquery DomWindow for all links on webpage

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to make the Example 3 on this page: http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html work for all links on a webpage (not only the ones with class="absoluteIframeDOMWindow" element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, possible:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').openDOMWindow({ 
       height:400, 
       width:700, 
       positionType:'absolute', 
       positionTop:50, 
       eventType:'click', 
       positionLeft:50, 
       windowSource:'iframe', 
       windowPadding:0, 
       loader:1, 
       loaderImagePath:'animationProcessing.gif', 
       loaderHeight:16, 
       loaderWidth:17 
    }); 
});
```

To call a method, run a query or change a property of some specific nodes via JQuery, you should have a look at [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Now I discovered two strange problems.
1)I'm using this script in a RSS displayer http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/googleajaxfeed3.shtml and it works for most links, but doesn't work for the generated links of twitter statuses (e.g http://twitter.com/IraHeatBeat/statuses/48228573173121024) - it loads the DOMWindow, but leaves it blank
2)The last portion of generated RSS links work like normal links (no DOMWindow, just follows the link)