# jQuery DomWindow doesn't work for twitter links + last portion of links work like normal links

Tags: jquery

I'm using this script ([jquery DomWindow for all links on webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329637/jquery-domwindow-for-all-links-on-webpage)) in a RSS displayer (http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/googleajaxfeed3.shtml) and I discovered two strange problems:

1)It works for most links, but doesn't work for the links of twitter statuses (e.g http://twitter.com/IraHeatBeat/statuses/48228573173121024) - it displays the DOMWindow, but leaves it blank.

2)The last portion of generated RSS links work like normal links (no DOMWindow, just follows the link). E.g the links for PM sport work like normal links:

```
<div>ERR Sport
<script type="text/javascript">
    //USAGE SYNTAX: new rssdisplayer("divid", "rssurl", numberofitems, "displayoptions")
    new rssdisplayer("ERR_sport", "http://sport.etv.ee/xml/spordiuudised.php", 12, "date")
</script>
    The Basketball Jones
<script type="text/javascript">
    //USAGE SYNTAX: new rssdisplayer("divid", "rssurl", numberofitems, "displayoptions")
    new rssdisplayer("TBJ", "http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheBasketballJones", 5, "date")
</script>
    PM Sport
<script type="text/javascript">
    //USAGE SYNTAX: new rssdisplayer("divid", "rssurl", numberofitems, "displayoptions")
    new rssdisplayer("PMsport", "http://sport.postimees.ee//rss/", 5, "date")
</script></div>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I created a workaround for the second problem by adding a hidden div at the end with an RSS feed script (like the ones in the code part of the question) in it.

But there's still the problem with the DOMWindow not displaying Twitter pages.
And I also discovered that it doesn't allow visiting Facebook via the DOMWindow, it just displays the link to Facebook.

Anyone?