# jquery DomWindow for all links on webpage in Firefox 4

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to make the Example 3 on this page: http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html work for all links on a webpage (not only the ones with class="absoluteIframeDOMWindow" element) in **Firefox 4**?

When I upgraded to Firefox 4, this solution didn't work any more: [jquery DomWindow for all links on webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329637/jquery-domwindow-for-all-links-on-webpage)

And there's still the issue that it doesn't open twitter links: [jQuery DomWindow doesn't work for twitter links + last portion of links work like normal links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350496/jquery-domwindow-doesnt-work-for-twitter-links-last-portion-of-links-work-like)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
$('a[href]').openDOMWindow(...);
```

This will do it for every link as you ask.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it still doesn't work in Firefox 4.0.1 - the links open like normal links.